# setting cookie in angularjs ajax $http.post call

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, rest

I have an Angular 1.5 app that calls a PHP web service via $http.post(). I am trying to set a cookie in the PHP service but have been unsuccessful so far. setcookie() returns TRUE but I don't see this cookie in Chrome. If I hit the service directly in the browser, it sets the cookie just fine. Any help is welcome... 
Thanks

```
login: function (data, success, error) {
      $http.post(urls.BASE_API + '/login', data, {withCredentials: true}).success(success).error(error);
    }
```

Comment: is the request being made cross domain (includes different port)?

Comment: the service is on a subdomain.. the call itself works fine, just no cookie is being set

Comment: then you need to use `withCredentials` header (see $http docs). Browsers consider different port , protocol or subdomain as cross domain and thus cookie handing is different

Comment: I do have that. I just added a code snippet above.

Comment: is it an httpOnly cookie? Have you checked in php what cookies are being sent?

Comment: I think I got it working. Yes, it's an httpOnly cookie and I also had to add {withCredentials: true} to my other $http calls. Thanks for your help!